# Dnsmasq fail to start at boot on Raspberry Pi 3 with Stretch OS

Tags: pi-3, networking, ethernet, raspbian-stretch

I have configured my Rpi3 as an ethernet router. Rpi3 is running on Stretch Raspbian OS.

dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=eth1
listen-address=192.168.2.1
bind-interfaces
server=8.8.8.8 # Forward DNS requests to Google DNS
domain-needed # Don't forward short names
bogus-priv
dhcp-range=192.168.2.2,192.168.2.100,12h
```

eth1 static ip is defined in dhcpcd.conf file

```
interface eth1
static ip_address=192.168.2.1/24
static routers=192.168.2.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.2.1
```

But dnsmasq is failed to start at boot. Therefore i want to run dnsmasq manually using `sudo service dnsmasq start` after that Rpi work as ethernet router.

What will be the cause which prevent dnsmasq from start?

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

This might be because dnsmasq is attempting to bind to the socket before it becomes available.

To verify, run `systemctl status dnsmasq -l`. Possible error messages:

> dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 192.168.2.1                                                                   : Cannot assign requested address
>   dnsmasq: unknown interface eth1

Solution 1a (easy): Do not use bind-interfaces

```
# Comment out this line
;bind-interfaces
```

Solution 1b (easy): Do not listen on specific address/interface

```
# Comment out these lines
;interface=eth1
;listen-address=192.168.2.1
;bind-interfaces
```

Solution 2 (harder): Find a way to start dnsmasq only after the network is ready

Comment: I am very interested in any information you can provide regarding "Solution 2". Looking at `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/dnsmasq.service` suggests that it runs after the network is up, but in my case I am trying to use it with `hostapd` which I think doesn't come up until later.

Comment: What if we comment the line `bind-interfaces` only?

Comment: @vishnu m c If the failure comes from trying to listen on an address before your network is up, then solely removing bind-interfaces wouldn't work

Comment: But commenting `bind-interface` worked for me. Then what will be the reason for the error?

Comment: @akgren_soar Could you please tell me? How it happens? Its worked for me by just commenting the line `bind-interfaces`

Comment: @vishnu m c I'm glad to hear that removing only bind-interfaces worked for you but it didn't work for me previously. I've also sold my rpi so I can't verify it. Thanks for your feedback anyways, I'll add it as a possible solution for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a wifi-ethernet bridge on Raspbian stretch. The trick for me was following the tips from SurferTim on this rasbperrypi forum post with a similar question to yours: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=192377

Anyhow, using those guidelines that worked for me and others, here is what I would do:

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
interface=eth1
dhcp-range=192.168.2.2,192.168.2.100,12h
```

/etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
interface eth1
static ip_address=192.168.2.2/24
```

/etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

ip rules

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A  POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE

sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
```

SurferTim says to sudo nano /etc/rc.local but I added here /lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/70-ipv4-nat => use a text editor

```
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat
```

In order to use normal interface names on boot edit /boot/config.txt

```
net.ifnames=0
```

Or...(achieves same as above) in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", 
ATTR{address}=="b8:ac:6f:65:31:e5", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", 
ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Do a reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

This worked for me and is the Raspbian stretch way to do things from what I understand. The raspberry pi forums are your friend :-) Happy Linuxing!